# Ahoy Top Events By Hash Property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ahoy

I am trying to find the proper way to get the top 5 (by count) events in a database based on a particular property in the events ("value"). I am also using the hightop gem to make it easier to get this top 5.

If I use:

```
Ahoy::Event.where(time: Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).top(:name, 5)
```

This works, but sorts by event name. I would like to sort by the "value" property which lives in that event. Here's what a typical event looks like:

```
<Ahoy::Event id: 229, visit_id: 318, user_id: 1, name: "Thing", properties: {"episode"=>"1", "title"=>"Test", "value"=>"Thing Ep 1: Test"}, time: "2017-11-02 11:34:10">
```

I have tried to do:

```
Ahoy::Event.where(time: Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).top("properties['value']", 5)
```

as well as:

```
Ahoy::Event.where(time: Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).top("properties ->> 'value'", 5)
```

but this yields the following error: "cannot subscript type text because it is not an array". Is there a way to actually do what I want?

Comment: Is it feasible to remove the double quotes?

Comment: no that yields a syntax error: 

`syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or tLAMBEG
_of_month).top(properties -> 'value', 5, nil: false)`

Comment: did you run `rails generate ahoy:stores:active_record`?  This is something specific from `postgresql` could be useful including the sql generated from the server and all the details and the sql tags...https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/alpine.LRH.2.00.1108310820490.21634@rray.drdc.mstc.ms.gov

Comment: Yes the generator was run post install.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `properties` column is a JSON column so using a JSON extraction operator (`->>`) with the `Arel.sql()` method to wrap the `properties->>'value'` expression will be a way to go:

```rb
Ahoy::Event.where(time: Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).top(Arel.sql("properties->>'value'"), 5)
```